# Copying ccaron from pdf broken with the times font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

There is problem with the pdf pdflatex generates from the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}
\v{c}\char"A3
\end{document}
```

When I copy the čč from the pdf using Acrobat Reader, I get ˇcˇc instead.
However when I don't select times, i.e. compile

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}
\v{c}\char"A3
\end{document}
```

pdflatex will use the default font SFRM1000 from the cm-super package, and when I copy the čč from the pdf, I get čč (which is what I expect).

Do you have any idea how to fix this or why this happens?

PS: I also filed this at https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/4502 some time ago but I haven't got any response.

Comment: sorry about the lack of response, however the latex bug address isn't the right place as the issue is somewhere between glyphtounicode.tex, pdftex, and the Times font, none of those are under the control of the latex team (although it would have been better if we had replied back  in February and said that.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, David. I understand that the latex team might not be under control. The surpising thing to me is that it works for one font but not for the other, both fonts being among the most popular TeX fonts. AFAICT, glyphtounicode is correct, since it contains \pdfglyphtounicode{ccaron}{010D} and that's what it should. However I don't know enough about how pdflatex handles fonts to have any idea where the unicode mapping is lost.

Comment: I guess that `glyphtounicode` does nothing because the c with caron is realized in `ptm` by superimposing the accent to the c.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: the problem is the vf which uses two chars to get the ccaron. But this is actually not necessary: the font has a ccaron. And it is a bit curious that the urw times uses a vf in the adobe folder. Who is responsable for this files?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes thanks Frank just said the same in gnats I'm not sure who (if anyone) maintains those vf now

Comment: @usertcl it's mapping glyph names to unicode but the issue is that the ptm font (as exposed to tex) does not have a glyph of that name it is using a construct with two glyphs, a caron and a c,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but Frank is wrong with claiming that the glyph isn't there. I can see it in the afm. And if you do (only for testing!) `\pdfmapline{=ptmr8r NimbusRomNo9L-Regu " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-t1.enc <utmr8a.pfb}` and then `\fonttable{ptmr8r}
` (with package fonttable) then I get a perfect ccaron at position 163.  So one could improve the font.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if I can grasp all details of the discussion but I have got an idea: ccaron is not in the enc file for NimbusRoman as it is not in fonts/afm/adobe/times/ptmr8a.afm, which belongs to Adobe Times 001.007 (20 Mar 1990). However later versions of Adobe Times, e.g. version 002.000 (1 May 1997), whose afm file R ships, do contain it, see https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/grDevices/inst/afm/Times-Roman.afm

Comment: I think would be sad if pdftex couldn't use those glyphs in NimbusRoman, which were apparently only added in Adobe Times 002.000.

Comment: Times maintained in the psnfss package, isn't it? I realized that the newer afm are provided by Adobe as part of the core 14 pdf fonts but I am not sure if the postscript core fonts have ever been updated. Does that mean that we would need some compatibility switch to enable the additional glyphs?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes the glyph seems to be there these days, but pretty sure it wasn't initially, that is when psnfss was done by SPQR. Now I agree that it would be nice if these extra glyphs are usable but most likely the mapping is incomplete so T1Encoding isn't the answer either. The question then is is there an ???encoding that could replace 8r.enc and actually work for a lot of the fonts that currecntly use 8renc (as a common denominator)? And if so is there somebody willing to do the necessary work? Not sure PSNFSS is really "maintained" with SPQR dead - maybe Walter still feels resonsible

Comment: @FrankMittelbach well it is a bit work -- it is not only the mapping that has to be changed (this would be rather easy), one also has to change/recreate all the intermediary .vf. Perhaps I find some time later but not before christmas ;-). Do you know if there are somewhere fontinst files and scripts for the fonts so that one don't have to do everything from scratch?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer my best guess is Walter Schmidt, I don't seem to have the fontinst files (that was basically done by SPQR way back and then taken over (?) by Walter, so he probably has them. Well, google is your friend (if you finally figure out what to use as a search string): ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/psnfss-source/

Comment: @FrankMittelbach ah, I think I even saw them once. Looks quite good, everything is in fi-patches/latin.mtx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I contacted Walter Schmidt: he says that as far as he can remember, the reason to use the pre-1997 fonts was compatibility with postcript. Thank you very much for considering to take the time to work on that.

Comment: Copy-paste now works for me in Okular even with characters which are definitely composite (e.g. `wcircumflex`) because they don't exist in T1. It would still be better to use the proper characters, if they exist in the font, but copy-paste seems not to be a problem. (`wcircumflex` probably doesn't exist in `utm` or `ptm`, unlike `ccaron`, so the issue is only hypothetical in that case. Few fonts include w or y with roofs.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach If they use `8r.enc` as a common denominator and the glyphs are similarly named, it would be fairly straightforward to adapt one of the existing T1 encoding bases with another to pick up anything for TS1. But you'd lose the drop-in-ability unless the Adobe fonts were updated, because only the URW fonts have these glyphs at the moment.

Comment: I have revised my answer to hopefully meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use the `accsupp` package to typeset the `\v{c}` in the `ptm` font, but to substitute Unicode `010D` as the copyable replacement text in the PDF.  I place this in a macro `\vc`.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
\newcommand\vc{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=010D}%
    \v{c}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
\v{c} and \char"A3 \ are not copyable, but
\vc{} is copyable.

{\sffamily \v{c} and \char"A3 \ are sans, and so is
\vc.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The document, when copy/pasted, yields:

```
ˇc and ˇc are not copyable, but č is copyable.
č and č are sans, and so is č.
```

However, as Ulrike notes, "this [approach] affects both kerning and hyphenation", because pdfliterals are being inserted.  Also, the success of this approach depends on whether the particular viewer supports "actualtext".  In my case, I used Adobe to view and copy/paste, which does support the function.

If this technique needs to be used for multiple caron characters, I would recommend a technique such as this, in which `\v` is redefined to use support macros that are created for all the needed caron characters.  Here, I demonstrate that with both č and ě, for which the support macros `\vc` and `\ve` have been created:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
\let\svv\v
\newcommand\vc{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=010D}%
    \svv{c}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\newcommand\ve{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=011B}%
    \svv{e}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\renewcommand\v[1]{\ifcsname v#1\endcsname
  \csname v#1\endcsname\else\svv{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
\v{c} is now copyable.

So is \v{e} but not \v{a}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Copy/paste yields:

```
č is now copyable.
So is ě but not ˇa.
```

Comment: Can you confirm the characters really aren't copyable for you? When I compile the original code, they copy fine. But I don't have Adobe Reader, so I thought maybe it is a limitation of that particular viewer? As I said in a comment, even `ŵ` copy-pastes fine for me and that is not even in the T1 encoding.

Comment: Result of compiling your code: `č and č are not copyable, but č is copyable.
č and č are sans, and so is č.` What difference am I supposed to see?

Comment: well at first actualtext is not recognized by every PDF viewer, so it works for me with adobe reader but not with the winedt reader. But more importantly: you are inserting pdfliterals, and this affects both kerning and hyphenation.

Comment: @cfr In the visually rendered PDF, upon running pdflatex, you should see no difference.  But in the copy/paste, the ones I deem "non-copyable" paste as "ˇc and ˇc", instead of "č".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I understand that and that is what I expected, but it isn't what happends. For me they don't copy-paste as composites, but as single characters. I compiled your code with pdfTeX and copy-pasted the output into my comment above. I don't understand why the non-copyable characters copy-paste correctly. Even `wcircumflex` copy-pastes correctly. Note that I can't reproduce the breakage using the OP's code, either. Copy-paste works regardless, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Very strange, @cfr

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I must be doing something stupid, but don't know what. At fist, I thought the fonts must have been updated since the question was asked and maybe the bounty-giver or journal had an old TeX. Hence the ŵ test. Since I know that is (annoyingly!) missing from T1, it shouldn't work even if it is included in the font. But I can't get it to not work in the way it should(n't)!

Comment: I could live with awkward hyphenation side effects and sub-optimal kerning as I only need \v accents in my bibliography; however, solutions that don't work in all PDF readers are troublesome for me.

Comment: @cfr What PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: @zwol   Okular...